# How can we remove Detached DOM in controller & Directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

Using dev tools, I did profiling of Ionic 1 apps (angular 1.*), I saw that it had lots of Detached DOM resulting in slow performance & memory growth.

I did profiling & saw it leads to increase of detached dom. After googling, I found that we need to use $destroy & clean up items. I have good number of custom directives & controllers.

I used this for custom directives

```
elem.on('$destroy', function() {               
                elem.off();
                $log.info('Inside destroy..' + elem);
            });

            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                scope = {};                
                $log.info("In destroy of:" + scope);
            });
```

How can I remove the DOM or scope elements from controllers, I know its similar code, but just *elem* in directive; how we can access DOM elements in controller for destroy.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are actually seeing is the default behavior in ionic due to its [caching](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/#caching) mechanism.

> By default, views are cached to improve performance. When a view is
>   navigated away from, its element is left in the DOM, and its scope is
>   disconnected from the $watch cycle. When navigating to a view that is
>   already cached, its scope is then reconnected, and the existing
>   element that was left in the DOM becomes the active view. This also
>   allows for the scroll position of previous views to be maintained.

If you want to disable it per view you can set the `<ion-view cache-view="false">` attribute. You can also do it globallly via `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);`.

Comment: so if I make cache-view="false" then how remove DOM elements. Cache view is already false.

Comment: It is removed automatically if cache is set to false. Did you review it in chrome dev tools? Is it still showing? What ionic version are you using?

Comment: I am using Ionic 1.3, we use lots of custom directives & controller, but i dont see them removed. They showup as Detached DOM